# How to display data taken from a gridview in a crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, crystal-reports

I have data taken from a gridview to a datatable. Now i want to display all these data in a crystal report.I wish to display them using a loop. How do i do it?
This is the code

```
string sColValues= "";

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    Context.Response.Write(dt);
                    sColValues += dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + " ";
                    Response.Write(sColValues + "</br>");
                    sColValues = "";

                }
            }
```

Comment: Please show us, what you have tried.

Comment: @ Jonathan Willcock I added the code used to print data. Now problem is to print the data inside the crystal report. when i execute the program it prints data out of the crystal report. Please help me to correct it.

Comment: First of all you need to create your Crystal report Report file (.rpt).  To do this, you need to have a table/view/stored procedure in a database that will return sample values.  When creating your report, you will be asked to connect to this data source, so that the WYSIWYG designer can help you with the layout of the report.  At runtime you can have a different connection to the one used at design time, but you must have created your report first.

Comment: I have all these things. In my system i get few user inputs to a gridview and i should enter it directly to the crystal report without inserting to the database. Here databse doesnt involve and yes i've created the report file already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include a datatable in a report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033562/include-a-datatable-in-a-report)